# Incluir uma ICollection<Entity> na consulta ao banco de dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta simples de ManyToOne, onde uma pessoa pode possuir vários emails (e telefones também, mas não vem ao caso, pois é o mesmo problema), mas simplesmente a lista de emails da Pessoa retorna sempre nula.

Tenho as seguintes entities:

```
public class EmailEntity
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public PessoaEntity Proprietario { get; set; }
   public Guid ProprietarioId { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class PessoaEntity
{
    // demais propriedades
    public ICollection<EmailEntity> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ClienteEntity : PessoaEntity
{
    // propriedades
}
```

A configuration:

```
public class PessoaConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PessoaEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PessoaEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Pessoa")
            .HasIndex(x => x.CpfCnpj);

        builder.HasMany(x => x.Telefones)
            .WithOne(y => y.Proprietario)
            .HasForeignKey(y => y.ProprietarioId);

        builder.HasMany(x => x.Emails)
            .WithOne(y => y.Proprietario)
            .HasForeignKey(y => y.ProprietarioId);
    }
}
```

Query que estou tentando fazer (ela possui filtros mais adiante, mas não vem ao caso aqui);

```
IQueryable<ClienteEntity> query = _dataContext.Cliente
   .Include(x => x.Emails)
   .Include(x => x.Telefones);
```

Será que o problema está acontecendo porque Cliente extende Pessoa ou alguma outra coisa que passei batido?

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Se você tirar o telefone do configuration da Pessoa e botar `builder.HasRequired(m => m.Cliente).WithMany(m => m.Emails).HasForeignKey(m => m.ClienteId);` no configuration do Email, funciona?

Comment: @NatanFernandes Alterei da seguinte maneira (pois o EFCore não tem o HasRequired) `builder.HasOne(x => x.Proprietario).WithMany(x => x.Telefones).HasForeignKey(x => x.ProprietarioId).IsRequired();` Mas infelizmente ainda continua dando o mesmo problema.

Comment: Acabei achando uma solução que funcionou no meu caso. [https://www.koskila.net/ef-core-returns-null-for-a-navigation-property/](https://www.koskila.net/ef-core-returns-null-for-a-navigation-property/)